# iPhone: Can I register to "Save to app" with Safari?

Tags: iphone, safari

Is it possible to register my app in some way so that when I download it in Safari, it saves to my application's folder?

Say for example I have a music app which I have written and while browsing with Safari, I want to download that MP3 file into my app. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to register with "Open With..." hook?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Yes, I think so. If I were able to "Open with" my app, then I could also save the content as well.